# Max Noether's theorem application

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve this problem that I've found on the Internet related to Max Noether's theorem [AF+BG theorem (also known as Max Noether's fundamental theorem)] . It uses the notation of Fulton's book: Algebraic curves.

> Consider the fractions C2/C2' of polynomials of degree 2. Given a such a fraction we need to find L such that L/x2 is the same meromorphic function on C (smooth cubic plane curve F(x0,x1,x2)=0 and P$\in$C an inflexion point with tangent line at P the line x2=0) as C2/C2'. Therefore, L.C2' - x2.C2 must be in the ideal (F). If C2/C2' $\in$ $L_{alg}(2P)$ (vector space given by rational functions), then {C2'=0}$\cap$C=2P + $\sum_{i=1}^{4}P_{i}$ and {C2=0)$\cap$C=R + S + $\sum_{i=1}^{4}P_{i}$. Take G=C2' and apply Noether's theorem to these F and G with H=x2.C2

I cannot see how to use Noether's theorem to this purpose...

Any ideas?

Comment: [Which one?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Noether's_theorem) ("In mathematics, Max Noether's theorem in algebraic geometry may refer to at least six results of Max Noether.")

Comment: AF+BG theorem (also known as Max Noether's fundamental theorem)